# Double Validation (Re-typing) in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have been asked to create a validation rule in a visual flow that requires a user to type a value twice. Then the validation rule will compare the two values typed (ignoring case) then if they are not equal the validation rule will fire and they will need to re-enter. This will be similar to how you check a password or email address on many web forms. The second value won't need to be saved, so I don't really want to create a new field that is never saved (it seems like a bad practice). Has anyone done this or have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a validation rule or a field. You can build this logic in the Flow directly. That design will look like the following:

[image: Flow Decision]

Obviously, you'll need to tweak this a bit to suit your purposes, but it should be straightforward once you have the proper layout.

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting solution, however the field has to be on a form with a lot of other input, I'm not sure I could go to a second screen for re-entry.

Comment: @ScottH7a9 You don't need the second screen; that was just for demonstrative purposes. They can easily both be on the same screen.

Comment: Okay, this was helpful and solved the problem. Thank you @sfdcfox